# Positive Definite Matrix Multiplication Non-Symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

If we have $B$ is an $(n,n+1)$ matrix and $A$ is a positive definite $(n,n)$ matrix is the resulting quantity positive definite?

$$B^TAB$$

It seems like it should be since we have both a $B^T$ and a $B$ in there and we know that $B^TB$ is positive definite, but I am getting stuck on an explicit proof.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never positive definite. $B$ is a fat matrix. Thus $Bx=0$ has a nontrivial solution $x$ and $x^TB^TABx=0$.

Comment: Hmm what is a fat matrix?

Comment: Do all fat matrices have a guaranteed solution?

Comment: @user2879934 When the number of columns exceeds the dimension of the vector space, the columns must be linearly dependent.

Comment: What about semi-positive definite?

Comment: Interesting, so if both A and B are semi-positive definite, does that rearrangement guarantee that quantity is >= 0. Sorry B can't be PSD

Comment: Right sorry, I realized that as soon as I posted :)

Comment: I'm just wondering if that quadratic form re-arrangement gets us anything

Comment: Sorry, not totally seeing why?

Comment: @user2879934 Let $v=Bx$. Then $x^TB^TABx=(Bx)^TA(Bx)=v^TAv$, which is $\ge0$ because $A$ is positive definite.